# sqlite column width

Tags: sqlite, schema

i'm executing PRAGMA table_info over a sqlite db

```
PRAGMA table_info(my_table);
```

And these are the columns retrieved:

name
type
notnull
dflt_value
pk

I noted there is no column width in case of (n)(var)char data types, ¿is there any easy way to get this info?

NOTE: I know there is no problem inserting large values in these columns, however, i wanna access this metadata anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When checking the content of the query result:
PRAGMA table_info(my_table);

the type column contains

- (n)(var)char for columns with width 1
- (n)(var)char(x) for columns with width greater than 1

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q9:

> SQLite does not enforce the length of a VARCHAR. You can declare a VARCHAR(10) and SQLite will be happy to let you put 500 characters in it. And it will keep all 500 characters intact - it never truncates.

So basically, SQLite doesn't really have a length on those fields, it'll happily accept anything.

Comment: yeah, i know it, but he keeps a column width on the metadata (I use SQLite Expert and on the table design, he keeps the size of the column)

Comment: There's a rumor that in the future if you use the new STRICT table type, it will enforce column lengths (not just types), but I can't confirm or deny. Anyone? If one assumes SQLite ignores stated column length and SQLite "fixes" the strict mode to enforce, a database version update could break a lot of existing projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the meta data by doing a select from the sqlite_master table